# Write a makefile with one rule for many targets?

Tags: python, windows, qt, makefile, pyqt4

It may seem as a very simple question, but I could not find any way to fix it.

My intention is to convert every ".ui" file into a ".py" file by invoking the pyuic4 command (from [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro)). I tried to manage this with a very short makefile:

```
%.py: %.ui
    pyuic4 $< --output $@
```

That's all I need at the moment.

The makefile is named "Makefile" and located in the folder where "make" is invoked from, and so are the ".ui" files. "pyuic4(.bat)" is in the system's path (Windows 7), and so are the [Unix Utilities](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) where "make" is part of.

When running "make" from the Windows console, it says:

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Invoking pyuic4 from the command line with explicit file names works.

I know I could specify any target file by its own, but if possible I want to avoid this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your example works for me on linux. Maybe try the -d option to make to see what is going wrong?

Comment: Thank you, @suvayu Supposedly it is looking for an implicit rule for a file called "Makefile", which I cannot understand. I'm using make 3.80.

Comment: The rule you defined requires you to use the command "make <filename>.py" where <filename> is the name of the file you want to generate.  Make does not automatically assume you want to convert all ui files to py files.

Comment: @ChristophJüngling I overlooked that you were just calling `make`.  As mentioned by @kasterma, you have to type `make filename` with your current Makefile.

Comment: @suvayu ... because I don't have a single target specified, which concentrates all actions to this one point? Ok, then it would be better to use a simple shell script, as eriktous wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the problem could be solved by either perror's or eriktous' solution, I'm now going the third way as mentioned by eriktous by simply invoking the pyuic4 command with a shell script. It's running quite fast and even if the output will result in identical files, no harm will be done for the source code control.

I encountered a second point, which may have distracted me. The pyuic4 command is really named pyuic4.bat, which is a "batch file" in Windows, similar to shell scripts in a Linux/Unix environment; similar, but not identical. If a batch file is invoked from another batch file it should be invoked with a leading "call" statement to prevent termination of the batch after the first invocation.

If I have three files (the @ sign is to prevent the command from being listed during execution)

```
D:\Projekte\test>type main.cmd
@sub1
@sub2

D:\Projekte\test>type sub1.cmd
@echo This is sub 1

D:\Projekte\test>type sub2.cmd
@echo This is sub 2
```

... the result is just

```
D:\Projekte\test>main
This is sub 1
```

So my "solution" for this very small thing is a simple batch file called "update.cmd", which may be expanded by copies of this line:

```
call pyuic4 mainwindow.ui --output mainwindow.py
```

That's not what I initially wanted, but it works for me.

But anyway, thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 5):

As per kasterma's comment, you need to tell make which target to build, but you've only provided a pattern rule. This can be done in the following way.

```
UIFILES := $(wildcard *.ui)
PYFILES := $(UIFILES:.ui=.py)

.PHONY: all
all: $(PYFILES)

%.py: %.ui
    pyuic4 $< --output $@
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are obviously using a GNU Makefile syntax, I would advise you to write your rule like this:

```
UIFILES = $(wildcard *.ui)

.PHONY: ui2py

ui2py: $(UIFILES)
        @for uifile in $(UIFILES); do \
                pyuic4 $$(uifile) --output $${uifile%.ui}.py; \
        done
```

Comment: Now I got another error:

abnormal program termination
C:\Users\...\Temp\make9642.sh: fork failed: no error [1]
make: *** [ui2py] Error 1

Comment: Hmmm, do you really trust your hardware or your system ? Because, it looks like the problem is not about the Makefile but at a lower level.

Comment: no I don't, it's Windows :-) I'll try this on the old XP machine, where a much bigger makefile worked fine.

Comment: This is just a shell script in disguise. There is hardly any need to use make, if you're going this way, (which may just be the right way to go for the OP).